# Is there a default folder for yas-snippets?

Tags: yasnippet

Does anyone know where `yas-lookup-snippet` gets its snippets from?
I recently did a few changes with my snippets and now face that every time I want to open a new file I get the message:

```
yas-lookup-snippet: No snippet named: dph
```

Presumably due to the:

```
(yas-expand-snippet (yas-lookup-snippet "dph" 'python-mode)))
```

That file exists in the following directories (from .emacs.d):

```
./snippets/dph
./elpa/elpy-20220627.1416/snippets/python-mode/dph
./elpa/yasnippet-snippets-20220713.1234/snippets/emacs-lisp-mode/dph
```

**(Edit)** Also I set the file correctly:

```
(use-package yasnippet
  :config
  (add-to-list 'yas-snippet-dirs "~/.emacs.d/snippets")
  (yas-global-mode 1))
```

It seems there's also

```
./elpa/yasnippet-snippets-20220713.1234/snippets/python-mode
```

However, adding it here doesn't change anything.

I struggle to figure out what's the default folder for `yas-lookup-snippet`?

Answer (score 2):

From the doc:

```
yas-snippet-dirs is a variable defined in ‘yasnippet.el’.

List of top-level snippet directories.

Each element, a string or a symbol whose value is a string,
designates a top-level directory where per-mode snippet
directories can be found.

Elements appearing earlier in the list override later elements’
snippets.

The first directory is taken as the default for storing snippet’s
created with ‘yas-new-snippet’.
```

Comment: I actually had the variable updated. (see Edit) Is there a way to output the dir in emacs?

Comment: @Qohelet Perhaps `:config` is too late. Try changing it to `:init` in `use-package`, which is what I saw in Spacemacs source code.

Comment: Changed it. Still the same. Any idea how to debug this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing `dph` is a personal snippet, as it's not in `yas-snippets` nor `elpy`. In the context of `yas-snippet` and your config, its correct location on the file system should be `~/.emacs.d/snippets/python-mode/dph`. When creating a new snippet, always use `yas-new-snippet` as it will "do the right thing" when you save it. Additionally, when expecting shell-like filename expansion always use `expand-file-name`, it'll save you some grief. So with the following config:

```lisp
(use-package yasnippet
  :config
  ;; my python-mode snippets will be in ~/.emacs/snippets/python-mode
  (add-to-list 'yas-snippet-dirs (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/snippets"))
  (yas-global-mode 1))

(use-package yasnippet-snippets
   :requires yasnippet)
```

Inspecting `yas-snippet-dirs` with `C-h v` should show:

```
yas-snippet-dirs is a variable defined in ‘yasnippet.el’.

Its value is
("/Users/nega/.emacs.d/snippets" yasnippet-snippets-dir)
Original value was 
("/Users/nega/.emacs.d/snippets")

List of top-level snippet directories.

Each element, a string or a symbol whose value is a string,
designates a top-level directory where per-mode snippet
directories can be found.

Elements appearing earlier in the list override later elements’
snippets.

The first directory is taken as the default for storing snippet’s
created with ‘yas-new-snippet’. 

  This variable has the following aliases: `yas/snippet-dirs',
    `yas/root-directory'.
  You can customize this variable.

[back]
```

I'd guess, based on your config that you're seeing something like:

```
Its value is
("~/.emacs.d/snippets" "/home/Qohelet/.emacs.d/snippets" yasnippet-snippets-dir)
Original value was 
("/home/Qohelet/.emacs.d/snippets")
```